# How to remove same value from var

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to remove same value from two var variable, This is what i have tried.

```
var  first_list =   [1,10,12,20] ;
var  sec_list   =   [1,10,12,20,56];

sec_list.RemoveAll(first_list.Contains);
```

But it' snot working, values are not removed.

This is the expected result

`sec_list = [56]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `sec_list = { 56 }`.

```
int[] first_list = { 1, 10, 12, 20 };
int[] sec_list = { 1, 10, 12, 20, 56 };
sec_list = sec_list.Except(first_list).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
int[] first_list = { 1, 10, 12, 20 };
int[] sec_list = { 1, 10, 12, 20, 56 };
var list = sec_list.Except(first_list);
sec_list = list.ToArray();
```